# Tensorflow hangs with high CPU usage for training a very small forest

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried the following code in order train a very small random forest as a test, but for some reason it hangs with high CPU usage. I think it possibly might have to do with the hash table not being initialized, but I am not sure where it should be initialized to be accessible by both input_fn and the call to 'estimator.evaluate'. Any advice?

```
import csv
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.cloud.python.ops import bigquery_reader_ops
from tensorflow.contrib.lookup import KeyValueTensorInitializer, HashTable
from tensorflow.contrib.tensor_forest.client.random_forest import TensorForestEstimator
from tensorflow.contrib.tensor_forest.python.tensor_forest import ForestHParams
from tensorflow.python.training.input import string_input_producer

sess = tf.Session()

with open('event_classes.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    event_names, event_numbers = list(zip(*[(r[0], int(r[1])) for r in reader]))


def input_fn():
    # Create maps between event names and event numbers
    event_class_map = HashTable(KeyValueTensorInitializer(
        event_names, event_numbers, key_dtype=tf.string, value_dtype=tf.int64), int(0))
    reverse_event_class_map = HashTable(KeyValueTensorInitializer(
        event_numbers, event_names, key_dtype=tf.int64, value_dtype=tf.string), "Unknown")

    # Specify features to read
    features = {"time_{}".format(i): tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.string, default_value="") for i in range(4)}

    # Create a Reader.
    reader = bigquery_reader_ops.BigQueryReader(project_id="drivemode-com",
                                                dataset_id="temp_stephane",
                                                table_id="event_history",
                                                timestamp_millis=1497502522,
                                                num_partitions=1,
                                                features=features)

    # Populate a queue with the BigQuery Table partitions.
    queue = string_input_producer(reader.partitions())

    # Read and parse examples.
    row_id, examples_serialized = reader.read_up_to(queue, 100)
    examples = tf.parse_example(examples_serialized, features=features)

    # Process the Tensors example["name"], example["age"], etc...
    for i in range(4):
        col = "time_{}".format(i)
        examples[col] = event_class_map.lookup(examples[col])
    # event_class_map.init.run(session=sess)
    label = examples.pop("time_3")
    return examples, label


hparams = ForestHParams(num_classes=len(event_numbers), num_features=3, max_nodes=3, num_trees=1).fill()
estimator = TensorForestEstimator(hparams)
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1)
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)
print sess.run(estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn))
```

Comment: Here we go, as a comment: Does it hang during training or evaluation?

One thing to note is that you don't need to explicitly create a session (or call start_queue_runners) when using an Estimator, it does that for you internally. And in fact trying to do anything with the model with your own session won't work.

Comment: Thank you. I got a little further by eliminating the 'start_queue_runners', but I found out that applying the accuracy estimator on the result then did make it segfault. Is it again something I did wrong or would you say that the RandomForest is still a little unstable?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at your code.  TensorForestEstimator uses it's own metrics, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/random_forest_mnist.py.